# When should the word "dump" be used?

Tags: exception, dump

It seems that the word "dump" or "dumping" is often used when a program get the memory content or some data that we cannot get directly. So when should we use that word properly?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump

Answer (score 0):

Dump is typically used when you are getting the raw data, right from the disk or RAM, unfiltered.

Comment: or any other raw data, mostly in an unformatted way (that is binary as hex or the like). Network monitors dump the traffic on the network for example